Nextjs Suspense works locally but not in production
I am running into a weird issue where my suspense works locally but does not work in production. When I visit my webapp locally everything is working as expected - the area outside the suspense (header, footer, etc) loads in right away while the area inside the suspense displays my spinner while waiting for the backend to send the data over. I am using "key" for my suspense and using my searchParams as for the key.
However, when I deploy the webapp to production, when visiting the webapp it does not load at all until the entire call to the backend is complete. My webapp does not get displayed at all until everything is done loading.
The even weirder part is that I can run the build command on my webapp locally and run it and it works as expected. It's only when the built webapp is up on my production environment that this occurs.
Here is some excerpts from my code where the suspense is set up as well as a video to make it clear whats going on
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QowXDkbanoA
export default async function SearchResultsPage({
  searchParams: {term, resultsPerPage=50, page=1}
}: {
  searchParams: any
}) {
  return (
    <>
      <Suspense key={term + resultsPerPage + page} fallback={<LoadingSpinner />}>
        <SearchResultsContainer term={term} resultsPerPage={resultsPerPage} page={page} />
      </Suspense>
    </>
  );
}

export async function SearchResultsContainer({
  term, resultsPerPage, page,
}: OnlineIdSearchParams) {
    const searchResults = await searchAccounts(term, page, resultsPerPage)
    return (
        <>
            <ul>
                {searchResults.map((searchResult) => (<li key={searchResult.id}>{searchResult.name}</li>))}
            </ul>
        </>
    );
}

Any help would be greatly appreciated!
I tried using startTransition when navigating to the page without any luck.
